# Unable to import torch.distributed.rpc

Tags: python, pytorch, rpc, distributed, torchvision

I was trying to run the RPC rnn example from the following link - https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/distributed/rpc/rnn

but I am unable to import RPC module of the torch.distributed and getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import torch.distributed.rpc as rpc
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rpc\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import backend_registry
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rpc\backend_registry.py", line 8, in <module>
    import torch.distributed.distributed_c10d as dc10d
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\distributed_c10d.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .rendezvous import rendezvous, register_rendezvous_handler  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rendezvous.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import FileStore, TCPStore
ImportError: cannot import name 'FileStore' from 'torch.distributed' (C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\__init__.py)
```

Torch Version:
torch                              1.4.0+cpu
torchvision                        0.5.0+cpu

Comment: [Github issue link](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/issues/716)

Comment: Can you import other torch subpackages correctly? Do you have multiple conda environments on your machine? Did you try to re-install already?

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch Distributed package does not support Windows yet. Requests for this feature is tracked here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37068